# Delete contents but not directory in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do you delete all content of directory but not delete the directory itself in Linux command line terminal?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "dir" is the directory, give the commands,

```
cd dir   
rm -r *
```

Comment: Not recommended in a script without some kind of checks. You risk data loss  if the cd operation fails or the dir is an empty variable or worse dir is something like "/$VAR1" and $VAR1 is empty.

Answer (score 9):

To remove everything under `$your_dir/`, including hidden files and directories, but without removing the `$your_dir` directory itself, you can use `find` :

```
find "$your_dir" -mindepth 1 -delete
```

An alternative with `rm` in Bash would be:

```
rm -rf "$your_dir"/{*,.[!.]*}
```

The second part in the curly braces ( `.[!.]*` ) takes care of hidden files which start with a dot, but only if they don't start with 2 dots. This avoids trying to remove `.` and `..`, but would still aslo remove a file named `.x`

Answer (score 3):

This will remove the hidden files or dot files and directory as well without any warning :)

```
rm -rf ..?* .[!.]* *
```

Answer (score 2):

`rm thedir/*` deletes non-directories in `thedir`.